# How to figure out if my DVD-reader is also a burner?

Tags: disk, dvd

I am using Ubuntu on a Dell Inspiron 14R. There are no writings like DVD-RX or DVD-rom on my DVD-reader. Is there anything in Ubuntu similar to the device manager in Windows, so that I can know if I have a DVD-burner or not?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's an alternative.

1. Open a new Terminal window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type in the following: `sudo apt-get install libcdio-utils`
2. Now there's a tool called `cd-drive` in the utility you've just installed. So in your Terminal run `sudo cd-drive` and hit enter.

The output should look like this:

```
cd-drive version 0.83 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (c) 2003, 2004, 2005, 2007, 2008, 2011 R. Bernstein
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
The driver selected is GNU/Linux
The default device for this driver is /dev/cdrom

Drivers available...
  GNU/Linux ioctl and MMC driver     
  cdrdao (TOC) disk image driver     
  bin/cuesheet disk image driver     
  Nero NRG disk image driver         

CD-ROM drive supports MMC 3

                       Drive: /dev/cdrom
Vendor                      : TSSTcorp
Model                       : CD/DVDW TS-L632D
Revision                    : HH18
Profile List Feature
    DVD-R - Double-Layer Sequential Recording
    DVD-R - Double-layer Jump Recording
    DVD+R Double Layer - DVD Recordable Double Layer
    DVD+R - DVD Recordable
    DVD+RW - DVD Rewritable
    Re-recordable DVD using Sequential Recording
    Re-recordable DVD using Restricted Overwrite
    Re-writable DVD
    Re-recordable DVD using Sequential recording
    Read only DVD
    CD-RW Re-writable Compact Disc capable
    Write once Compact Disc capable
    Read only Compact Disc capable

Core Feature
    ATAPI interface

Morphing Feature
    Operational Change Request/Notification not supported
    Synchronous GET EVENT/STATUS NOTIFICATION supported

Removable Medium Feature
    Tray type loading mechanism
    can eject the medium or magazine via the normal START/STOP command
    can be locked into the Logical Unit

Write Protect Feature

Random Readable Feature

Multi-Read Feature

CD Read Feature
    C2 Error pointers are supported
    CD-Text is supported

DVD Read Feature

Random Writable Feature

Incremental Streaming Writable Feature

Formattable Feature

Management Ability of the Logical Unit/media system to provide an apparently defect-free space. Feature

Restricted Overwrite Feature

DVD+RW Feature

DVD+R Feature

Rigid Restricted Overwrite Feature

CD Track at Once Feature

CD Mastering (Session at Once) Feature

DVD-R/RW Write Feature

Unknown code 33 Feature

DVD+R Double Layer Feature

Profile List Feature

Profile List Feature

Profile List Feature

Unknown code c0 Feature

Profile List Feature

Profile List Feature

Profile List Feature

Profile List Feature

Profile List Feature

Profile List Feature

Profile List Feature

Morphing Feature
    Operational Change Request/Notification not supported
    Synchronous GET EVENT/STATUS NOTIFICATION supported

Profile List Feature

Profile List Feature
    Unknown Profile 0
    Unknown Profile 0
    Unknown Profile 0

Hardware                                  : CD-ROM or DVD
Can eject                                 : Yes
Can close tray                            : Yes
Can disable manual eject                  : Yes
Can select juke-box disc                  : No

Can set drive speed                       : No
Can read multiple sessions (e.g. PhotoCD) : Yes
Can hard reset device                     : Yes

Reading....
  Can read Mode 2 Form 1                  : Yes
  Can read Mode 2 Form 2                  : Yes
  Can read (S)VCD (i.e. Mode 2 Form 1/2)  : Yes
  Can read C2 Errors                      : Yes
  Can read IRSC                           : Yes
  Can read Media Channel Number (or UPC)  : Yes
  Can play audio                          : Yes
  Can read CD-DA                          : Yes
  Can read CD-R                           : Yes
  Can read CD-RW                          : Yes
  Can read DVD-ROM                        : Yes

Writing....
  Can write CD-RW                         : Yes
  Can write DVD-R                         : Yes
  Can write DVD-RAM                       : Yes
  Can write DVD-RW                        : No
  Can write DVD+RW                        : No
```