# How can I know if DVD drives can burn Double Layer?

Tags: dvd-backup

For some reasons I would like to know is I can use any command line (or other) to know if some DVD burner can burn DVD DoubleLayer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to figure out if my DVD-reader is also a burner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313231/how-to-figure-out-if-my-dvd-reader-is-also-a-burner)

Comment: Old answer, still up to date? Do you suggest I should look for  info "DVD-R - Double-Layer Sequential Recording" in output? But install a package just for that? Is sudo lshw | grep dvd not enough? I got "removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram" so no dvd-DL?

Comment: yes it is. `cd-drive` will show far more info and it more readable.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still not explicit. I tried cd-drive and got exactly the same output as the example  in your link, so "DVD+R Double Layer - DVD Recordable Double Layer" but nothing about DVD DL in writing section. So what?

Comment: "DVD Recordable Double Layer" would be what you want to see? This means would can record/write DL dvd's